# Drawing squares of functions

Tags: functions

If I want to sketch the square of the sinc function, or any function for that matter, is there a neat transformation technique which would allow one not to refer to graphing devices for this task?

Comment: It shouldn't be any harder than if you didn't have the squaring: plot enough points on the graph numerically to get a feel for the shape of the curve and then interpolate to the best of your ability.

Comment: Yes, but I'd prefer something like a transformation, without the need of sketching distinct points.

Comment: If you want to be cheeky about it you could just keep the same graph, remove the negative portion of the $y$-axis, and replace every point on the positive $y$-axis with its square. Easy peasy!
Of course, this is completely useless and gives you no idea what the squared graph looks like next to the original graph :/.

Answer (score 1):

Apart from what has been said already, you also need to note that at any of the points where $f(x)=0$ has single roots, there will be double roots when solving $[f(x)]^2=0$. This means that the graph of $y=[f(x)]^2$ will **touch** the $x$ axis at these points.

Note that $\frac{d}{dx}[f(x)]^2=2f'(x)f(x)=0$ when $f(x)=0$

Answer (score 0):

If you're satisfied with a rough sketch, just draw (or imagine) two lines, $y = 1$ and $y = -1$.

Since $x^2 \leq |x| \Leftrightarrow |x| \leq 1$, every point on the graph that falls between the two lines maps to a positive point of correspondingly smaller absolute value than that of the original point. Everything that lies outside of the two lines maps to a positive point that has correspondingly larger absolute value than that of the original point.

You can carry this idea further by drawing lines at regular intervals ($y = \pm 2, y = \pm3$, etc, you can draw them closer or further apart as you wish), and just map every point that falls between the $i$-th and $(i+1)$-st lines (or the "$-i$-th" and "$-(i+1)$-st" lines) to a positive point of absolute value between $i$ and $(i+1)$ times that of the original point.

The idea here is that you don't actually have to plot the squared graph point-by-point (I understand this is what you're trying to avoid), since with the horizontal lines you can just follow along the original curve, drawing a smooth curve as you go, and come up with a half-decent drawing (tried it myself with a random graph, seems to work out pretty well).